# Primefaces Panel

Tags: primefaces

Is there a way to make it so that when I click a p:button a hidden p:panel appears and is hidden again the next time that it is rendered?

```
            <h:commandButton id="saveButton"  value="save" oncomplete="cartComplete.show();">
            </h:commandButton>
            <p:panel widgetVar="cartComplete">
                Shopping Cart Saved
            </p:panel>
```

Comment: _"and is hidden again the next time that it is rendered"_ What does it mean? Page reload?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{myBean.setPanelVisibility}" update=":myForm:myPanel"/>
<p:panel id="myPanel" rendered="#{myBean.renderPanel}"/>
```

In the bean toggle the renderPanel attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:panel id="myPanel" style="display:none">
            Shopping Cart Saved
        </p:panel>
        <p:commandButton id="show" value="show" onclick="jQuery('#myPanel').show()">
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton id="hide" value="hide" update="myPanel">
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

explanation : style="display:none" make the panel be hidden, and whenver you want to display it use jquery (which comes already with primefaces) .show() function, and finally the `update="myPanel"` of the second command button will re-render the panel , and it will be hidden again...

---

Update

Same idea just with `styleClass`,  use `styleClass="hide"` (instead of `style="display:none"`)

where in your css

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: How would you accomplish this though if you need a styleClass with the panel?

Answer (score 0):

in java class

private String renderPanel = "false";
`<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{myBean.setPanelVisibility}" update="myPanel"/>
<p:panel id="myPanel" rendered="#{myBean.renderPanel=='true'}"/>`